How to skip R package articles/vignettes in GitHub checks
I've written a package that got published to CRAN called cepumd. I decided to write some articles using usethis::build_article() to show some different uses of the package functions. In the articles I have to load data from a path that I call in the RMarkdown. This path is making the package fail R CMD tests on GitHub even though I added the vignettes/articles directory to .Rbuildignore. Does anyone have any thoughts on how I might have these article files skipped on GitHub?
The package is here: https://github.com/arcenis-r/cepumd
The exact file that it's failing on (due to line 34) is: https://github.com/arcenis-r/cepumd/blob/master/vignettes/articles/ce-estimates-by-demographics.Rmd
I also added args to my R-CMD-check workflow to ignore vignettes per what I read on another SO post: R: Skip a vignette being run on CRAN R CMD check
